# Use pandas python to filter and combine multiple cells into one cells Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm having a table with multiple columns and repeating data on all of the columns, except one (Address).

```
Last Name   First Name  Food    Address
Brown       James       Apple   1
Brown       Duke        Apple   2
William     Sam         Apple   3
Miller      Karen       Apple   4
William     Barry       Orange  5
William     Sam         Orange  6
Brown       James       Orange  7
Miller      Karen       Banana  8
Brown       Terry       Banana  9
```

I want to merge all first names sharing the same last name and food into one entry, and keep the first address found when that condition is met.
The result will look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know any functions in (pandas) python that allow me to add multiple cells into one? Also, what would be the best approach to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images. Instead, post the text form of tables as it should be easy for people to copy and not waste their time creating your requirements

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I have changed the input to text form

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. May be a faster way to put it all together, but in the end I pulled out rows with repeated First Names, transformed them, and put them back into the non-repeated dataframe.

I added another repeating row to be sure it worked with more than just two repeating names.

```
d = {'Last Name': ['Brown', 'Brown', 'Brown', 'William','Miller', 'William', 'William','Brown', 'Miller', 'Brown'], 
     'First Name':['Bill', 'James', 'Duke', 'Sam','Karen', 'Barry', 'Sam','James', 'Karen', 'Terry'], 
     'Food': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple','Apple', 'Orange', 'Orange','Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana'], 
     'Address': [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)


grp_df = df.groupby(['Last Name', 'Food'])

df_nonrepeats = df[grp_df['First Name'].transform('count') == 1]
df_repeats = df[grp_df['First Name'].transform('count') > 1]


def concat_repeats(x):
    dff = x.copy()
    temp_list = ' '.join(dff['First Name'].tolist())
    dff['First Name'] = temp_list
    dff = dff.head(1)
    return dff
    
grp_df = df_repeats.groupby(['Last Name', 'Food'])

df_concats = grp_df.apply(lambda x: concat_repeats(x))    
df_final = pd.concat([df_nonrepeats, df_concats[['Last Name', 'First Name', 'Food', 'Address']]]).sort_values('Address').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_final)
```